# Swiftでinitに?がついてるときはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: swift

Swiftで以下のように `init` に `?` が付いてる時はどういう意味ですか？

また これを `!` で外す時は `guard let … ??` でいいですか？

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.copyInit()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> initに?がついてるときはどういう意味

[公式のSwift本](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/)で[Failable Initializer](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224)と呼ばれているものです。直訳すれば「失敗する可能性のあるイニシャライザ」と言うことになりますが、初期化の途中で失敗する可能性があり、失敗した場合には結果が`nil`になると言うイニシャライザです。

> これを!ではずす

「!ではずす」と言う言い方は意味をなさないので何のことかわかりませんが、強制アンラップ(`!`)を使わずに安全に使用したい場合、guard letに代表される条件付きバインディングを用いたり、`??`演算子で`nil`の場合のデフォルト値を補ってやると言うのは、Optional型を返すメソッドと同じになります。

Comment: 失敗した場合には結果がnilになると言うイニシャライザ Swiftではnilを許容しませんがnilの場合エラーではないのですか？ 挙動はどうなりますか？

Comment: @nana さん、「Swiftではnilを許容しません」と言うのはこの場合正しい認識とは言えません。Swift言語ではnilになりうるデータ型としてOptional型が用意されており、Optional型はnilになり得ます。Failable Initializerの値はOptional型です。

Comment: ということは nil でもスルー そのまま ということですか？

Comment: @nana さん、「スルーそのまま」と言うのが意味不明ですが、Failable Initializerを呼び出した結果は、Optional型ですから、Optional型を返すメソッドを呼んだ時と同じように「安全に使用」するようにしないといけません。

Comment: nilだったとしても何も起こらないのですか？

Comment: @nana さん、「Optional型を返すメソッドを呼んだときに結果がnilだったとしても何も起こらない」と同じ意味で、何も起こりません。